# Microsoft SSIS 2005. Can't Use Transactions

Tags: ssis, transactions

I have set the package `TransactionOption` to `Required` and `DataFlowTask`'s `TransactionOption` to `Supported`, but when I execute the package, I get an exception:

> [ADO NET Destination [82]] Error: The transaction has already been implicitly or explicitly committed or aborted

Why does this happen, and how can I fix it?

Answer (score 0):

Here is my solution [http://faiz.kera.la/2009/08/26/ssis-transaction-enabled-tasks-fail-due-to-msdtc]. I recommend a little googling before posting here, as per the StackOverflow guide lines.

Comment: I've read your post but it didn't help me. The problem is still here

Comment: Have you checked that MsDTC is running? And are you using database in a different machine?